# Setting a default page size for a WebAPI 2 OData service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an ODataController with an endpoint like this:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Customer> Get()
{
    return _context.Customers;
}
```

And this setting in the Register method of the WebApiConfig:

```
config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(100);
```

There are a lot of Customer entries and I don't want the client requesting too many at once as the query will take a very long time. Luckily this setting means if they do a request like this:

http://domain.com/api/Customers?$top=1000

It'll prevent them from retrieving them as it's higher than 100.

However, if they do a request like this:

http://domain.com/api/Customers

This then attempts to retrieve all customers, which I don't want.

I know I can set the page size like this:

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 10)]
public IQueryable<Customer> Get()
{
    return _context.Customers;
}
```

And this will only return 10 results, however I still want the user to be able to specify their own $top and $skip values for paging (and deciding how many results they want per page). What I want is for there to be a maximum of 100 and a default of 10.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

I tried the following but it doesn't work properly when using Expand clauses. Any other ideas?

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop = 100)]
public IQueryable<Customer> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Customer> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<Customer> query = _context.Customers;
    int? top = queryOptions?.Top?.Value;
    if (top == null)
    {
        query = query.Take(10);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define class:

```
public class EnableQueryWithDefaultPageSizeAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    const int pageSizeDefault = 10;

    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        int? top = queryOptions?.Top?.Value;
        if (top == null)
        {
            return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = this.PageSize == 0 ? pageSizeDefault : this.PageSize });
        }

        return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable); ;
    }
}
```

and use it instance of **EnableQuery**. See [this](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2308).

Comment: As the GitHub suggests, setting [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10)] works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same thing, but I was able to get it working. It looks like the order of parameters matters. You'll have to forgive me, I am very new at this and learning as I go, so I hope this actually helps.

My API controller looks like this:

```
    [EnableQuery(PageSize=100)]
    public IQueryable<APPLICATION_LOGS> Get()
    {
        return db.APPLICATION_LOGS;
    }
```

In my client, I am building a request and capturing the response:

```
        string entity = "/AuditApplicationLog";
        string expandOptions = "&$expand=APPLICATION, APPLICATIONS_SUBSYSTEMS, FILE";
        string parameters = "?$top=100&$count=true";
        string url = serviceUri + entity + parameters + expandOptions;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

This is all a practice project that I am just using to teach myself a few concepts.The page size in my API controller is set to 100 but you'll notice in the parameters variable I am setting a top value. If I set this value to 25, it will return 25. If I set it to 50, it will return 50 etc. Apparently the order I set the parameters matters. If I set the top value before the expand parameters, it works. If I attempt to set it after the expand parameters it returns the default 100, regardless of the value I set top at. It does appear to leave out the "nextPage" link, but that can be accounted for. I hope this helps.